# How to connect FSCrawler REST with docker-compose

Tags: elasticsearch, docker-compose, fscrawler

I've successfully indexed a pdf using FSCrawler but I'm not able to connect to the REST client for FSCrawler to make a pipeline to elasticsearch. This is my command in docker-compose:

```
command: fscrawler fscrawler_rest
```

I'm able to query elasticsearch with the index of my FSCrawler job name and retrieve the results. Then when I add the `--rest` flag to my docker-compose command I successfully start the REST client (albeit with a warning I don't understand):

```
WARN  [o.g.j.i.i.Providers] A provider fr.pilato.elasticsearch.crawler.fs.rest.UploadApi registered in SERVER runtime does not implement any provider interfaces applicable in the SERVER runtime. 
      Due to constraint configuration problems the provider fr.pilato.elasticsearch.crawler.fs.rest.UploadApi will be ignored.
INFO  [f.p.e.c.f.r.RestServer] FS crawler Rest service started on [http://127.0.0.1:8080/fscrawler]
```

Then when I try `curl` with or without the trailing slash: `curl -XGET "127.0.0.1:8080/fscrawler/"` I get `curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 8080: Connection refused`

new docker-compose command for reference:

```
command: fscrawler fscrawler_rest --loop 0 --rest debug
```

I can't seem to debug it well as docker-compose doesn't allow CLI commands while containers are running, but I don't understand why I can still reach my job index in elasticsearch with `http://localhost:9200/fscrawler_rest`.

FSCrawler is working with elasticsearch but the REST service doesn't seem to be working. Has anyone been successful using the FSCrawler REST API?

EDIT:

```
version: '3.6'

services:
  postgres:
    image: "postgres:12.1"
    env_file:
      - '.env'
    ports:
      - '127.0.0.1:5432:5432'
    restart: "${DOCKER_RESTART_POLICY:-unless-stopped}"
    stop_grace_period: "${DOCKER_STOP_GRACE_PERIOD:-3s}"
    volumes:
      - postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    networks: 
      - esnet

  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.8.0
    # build: ./es
    container_name: elasticsearch
    env_file:
      - ".env"
    depends_on:
      - "postgres"
    volumes:
      - esdata:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    environment:
      - node.name=elasticsearch
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
      - discovery.type=single-node
      - network.host=0.0.0.0
      - network.publish_host=0.0.0.0
      - http.cors.enabled=true
      - http.cors.allow-origin=*
      - http.host=0.0.0.0
      - transport.host=0.0.0.0
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
      - 9300:9300
    networks:
      - esnet

  fscrawler:
    # I have taken this docker image and updated to 2.7 snapshot: toto1310/fscrawler
    build:
      context: ${PWD}
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-toto
    container_name: fscrawler
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ${PWD}/config:/root/.fscrawler
      - ${PWD}/data:/tmp/es
    networks: 
      - esnet
    environment:
      - FS_URL=/tmp/es
      - ELASTICSEARCH_URL=http://elasticsearch:9200
      - ELASTICSEARCH_INDEX=fscrawler_rest
    command: fscrawler fscrawler_rest --loop 0 --rest debug

volumes:
  postgres:
  esdata:
    driver: local

networks:
  esnet:
```

Comment: Could you please show the docker-compose file?

Comment: The WARN message looks weird to me. Could you open an issue in FSCrawler project please? With full details like the docker-compose file as well.

Comment: Also, could you run this without docker-compose? So we can check if the root of the problem is in FSCrawler or elsewhere.

Comment: @dadoonet I have opened an issue https://github.com/dadoonet/fscrawler/issues/984. If we can get this to work with compose I'm happy to update the docs accordingly as they're pretty sparse for docker at the moment.

Comment: @Dmitry See edits for docker-compose file

Comment: I think you need add ports to `fscrawler` container

Answer (score 2):

Adding ports to fscrawler

```
ports:
  - 8080:8080
```

gives empty response unless you change the `settings.yaml` rest url:

```
rest:
  url: “http://fscrawler:8080”
```

To reach the docker container named `fscrawler`.